# Query XML document - how to skip when no result or adjust index?

Tags: xml, vba, excel

(Originally titled "RunTime Error 91 - XML object variable not set. Works half the time?")

I have a VB script that opens an XML document and pulls some information from it.

```vb
Function fnReadXMLByTags(address As String) As String
    ' Part of of adapted from http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-read-data-from-xml-file/
    Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim mainWS  As Worksheet
    Dim addressArray()
    Dim addressArrayLen As Integer
    Dim tempi As Integer
    Dim latitude As Double, longitude As Double
    Dim county As String, altAddress As String

    'Let's add the addresses to look up into our array:
    lastRow = Cells(50000, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow > 1 Then
        addressArray() = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1))
    Else
        addressArray() = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 1))
    End If
    addressArrayLen = UBound(addressArray) - LBound(addressArray) + 1

    Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set mainWS = Sheets("Sheet1")
    mainWS.Range("A:A").Clear
    Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

    Dim startRow As Integer, adrRow As Integer
    startRow = Cells(50000, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For k = LBound(addressArray) To UBound(addressArray)

        If addressArray(k, 1) = "" Then Exit For
        strAddress = addressArray(k, 1)    ' URLEncode(Address)
        'Assemble the query string
        strQuery = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?"
        strQuery = strQuery & "address=" & strAddress
        strQuery = strQuery & "&sensor=false"
        Debug.Print strQuery
        XMLFileName = strQuery

        oXMLFile.async = False
        oXMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)

        Set latitudenodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat/text()")
        Set LongitudeNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng/text()")
        Set addressNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address/text()")
        Set countyNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type='administrative_area_level_2']/long_name/text()")
        Dim totalCoords As Integer

        With mainWS
            .Range(.Cells(startRow, 1), .Cells(startRow, 4)).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
            .Range(.Cells(startRow, 1), .Cells(startRow, 4)).Borders.Value = 1
            .Range("A" & startRow).Value = "Lookup Address: " & strAddress
            .Range("B" & startRow).Value = "Latitude"
            .Range("C" & startRow).Value = "Longitude"
            .Range("D" & startRow).Value = "Total Coordinates: " & latitudenodes.Length
            If latitudenodes.Length = 0 And addressNodes.Length = 0 And countyNodes.Length = 0 Then
                mainWS.Cells(startRow + 1, 1).Value = "No such address found for '" & strAddress & "'"
            End If
            For i = 0 To (latitudenodes.Length - 1)
                tempi = i
                latitude = latitudenodes(i).NodeValue
                longitude = LongitudeNodes(i).NodeValue
                altAddress = addressNodes(i).NodeValue
                county = countyNodes(i).NodeValue ' THIS IS THE LINE THAT THROWS THE ERROR!!!!!!-----------

                i = .Cells(40000, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 3)).Borders.Value = 1
                .Range("B" & i).Value = latitude
                .Range("C" & i).Value = longitude
                .Range("A" & i).Value = altAddress
                .Range("E" & i).Value = county
                i = tempi
            Next i

            lastRow = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
            If lastRow = 1048576 Then lastRow = 2

        End With 'End the With mainWS

        startRow = lastRow + 1
    Next k

    lastRow = mainWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If IsEmpty(mainWS.Cells(i, 4)) Then
            mainWS.Cells(i, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK(""https://www.google.com/maps/place//@""&RC[-2]&"",""&RC[-1]&"",16z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0"",""Link"")"
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```

If I have a list of addresses in column A, this macro runs fine for many of the addresses... however, after some point (seems to be when `i` >= 28), when trying to set `county = countyNodes(i).NodeValue` I get the error:

> Object variable or With block not set.

How come?  It doesn't do this for any of the other things (`latitude`, `longitude`, `altAddress`). Methinks it's to do with the actual XML...

Thanks for any ideas!

Edit: Here's an XML page that, when loaded, contributes to the error: [Link](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1900%20Constantinople,%20#7,%20Laredo,%20Texas,%2078040,%20USA&sensor=false)

There are `administrative_area_level_2` tags in there, for each location.
Edit2:

Okay, I think the issue occurs when there are multiple addresses given.  In my A1 and A2, I have:

```
1600 Pennsylvania
1600 Pennsylvania Ave, Washington DC
```

So, when Google looks for `1600 Pennsylvania`, there are 30 possible matches.  The code runs without issue UNTIL the final 30th address ("Pennsylvania, Panama, OK 74951, USA"), from [this XML page](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600%20pennsylvania&sensor=false) .

So, I think the error has been narrowed down and it only occurs on the LAST address, when more than one match is found.

### Edit: Super big ups to @Bond - using his answer, I was able to end up with this final, working, code:

```vb
Function fnReadXMLByTags(address As String) As String
' Part of of adapted from http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-read-data-from-xml-file/
Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
Dim mainWS  As Worksheet
Dim addressArray()
Dim addressArrayLen As Integer
Dim tempi   As Integer
Dim latitude As Double, longitude As Double
Dim county As String, altAddress As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Let's add the addresses to look up into our array:
lastRow = Cells(50000, 1).End(xlUp).row
If lastRow > 1 Then
    addressArray() = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1))
Else
    addressArray() = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 1))
End If
addressArrayLen = UBound(addressArray) - LBound(addressArray) + 1

Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set mainWS = ActiveSheet ' Sheets("Sheet1")
mainWS.Range("A:A").Clear
Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

Dim startRow As Integer, adrRow As Integer
startRow = Cells(50000, 1).End(xlUp).row


For k = LBound(addressArray) To UBound(addressArray)

    If addressArray(k, 1) = "" Then Exit For
    strAddress = addressArray(k, 1)    ' URLEncode(Address)
    'Assemble the query string
    strQuery = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?"
    strQuery = strQuery & "address=" & strAddress
    ' Debug.Print strQuery
    ' strQuery = "C:\Users\lportmann.REKERDRES\Desktop\xml.xml"
    XMLFileName = strQuery

    oXMLFile.async = False
    oXMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)

    Set resultnodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result")


    With mainWS
        .Range(.Cells(startRow, 1), .Cells(startRow, 4)).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        .Range(.Cells(startRow, 1), .Cells(startRow, 4)).Borders.Value = 1
        .Range("A" & startRow).Value = "Lookup Address: " & strAddress
        .Range("B" & startRow).Value = "Latitude"
        .Range("C" & startRow).Value = "Longitude"
        .Range("D" & startRow).Value = "Total Coordinates: " & resultnodes.Length

        If resultnodes.Length = 0 Then
            .Cells(startRow + 1, 1).Value = "No address found for " & strAddress
                        lastRow = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).row
            If lastRow = 1048576 Then lastRow = 2

            startRow = lastRow + 1
        End If
        Dim n
        For Each n In resultnodes
            Set latitudenodes = n.SelectSingleNode("geometry/location/lat")
            Set LongitudeNodes = n.SelectSingleNode("geometry/location/lng")
            Set addressNodes = n.SelectSingleNode("formatted_address")
            Set countyNodes = n.SelectSingleNode("address_component[type='administrative_area_level_2']/long_name")
            Set partialmatch = n.SelectSingleNode("partial_match")
            Set statenodes = n.SelectSingleNode("address_component[type='administrative_area_level_1']/long_name")

            If Not latitudenodes Is Nothing Then latitude = latitudenodes.Text
            If Not LongitudeNodes Is Nothing Then longitude = LongitudeNodes.Text
            If Not addressNodes Is Nothing Then altAddress = addressNodes.Text
            If Not countyNodes Is Nothing Then
                county = countyNodes.Text
                Debug.Print altAddress & " is in " & county & ". " & strQuery
            ElseIf countyNodes Is Nothing Then county = ""
            End If

            If Not statenodes Is Nothing Then
                State = statenodes.Text
            ElseIf statenodes Is Nothing Then State = ""
            End If

            If Not partialmatch Is Nothing Then
                pmatch = partialmatch.Text
            End If


            Debug.Print pmatch


            If resultnodes.Length = 0 Then
                mainWS.Cells(startRow + 1, 1).Value = "No such address found for '" & strAddress & "'"
            End If

            i = .Cells(40000, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
            .Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 3)).Borders.Value = 1
            .Range("A" & i).Value = altAddress
            .Range("A" & i).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
            .Range("B" & i).Value = latitude
            .Range("C" & i).Value = longitude
            .Range("E" & i).Value = county
            .Range("F" & i).Value = IIf(pmatch = "true", "Partial Match", "Exact match")
            .Range("G" & i).Value = State

            lastRow = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).row
            If lastRow = 1048576 Then lastRow = 2

            startRow = lastRow + 1
            pmatch = ""
        Next n
    End With

Next k

lastRow = mainWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 2 To lastRow
    If IsEmpty(mainWS.Cells(i, 4)) Then
        mainWS.Cells(i, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK(""https://www.google.com/maps/place//@""&RC[-2]&"",""&RC[-1]&"",16z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0"",""Link"")"
    End If
Next i


ActiveWindow.Zoom = 60
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

Comment: Look at your XML, particularly for a county node that has empty content. If there is no NodeValue, then you'll get an AV when trying to access it.

Comment: Bruce, have you looked at the XML that's produced by Google for that address? Perhaps it doesn't have a `<type>administrative_area_level_2</type>` node?

Comment: I thought so too, but I'm 99% positive that there will always be such a node.  I did notice, that my `county` isn't being set to the right county when it does work. I think maybe that contributes to the error.  Could it have something to do with when I `Set` it? Is this the right format: `Set countyNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type='administrative_area_level_2']/long_name/text()")`

Comment: Looks right. I think we'd need to narrow this down as much as possible with a sample XML that _doesn't_ return the proper county or errors out trying.

Comment: @Bond - I thought it looked okay too.  I think the county being returned is correct...It seems to occur only when there are multiple possible addresses. See my updated OP.

Comment: There are only 27 instances of `administrative_area_level_2` in your XML but 28 instances of the other nodes. This address doesn't have a `level_2`: `600 Pennsylvania Avenue Southeast, Washington, DC 20003, USA`

Comment: Ahhh - and I am assuming that since there's one less `administrative_area_level_2` than other records, that's going to throw something off?  How can I account for the fact that there *won't* always be `administrative_area_level_2?  Something like: `If no admin_level_2 tag, then set County to "", otherwise use admin_level_2 tag`?

Comment: It's going to be tricky because each query you do is independent of one another. You may need to rethink how you're querying the XML and do it a `<result>` at a time instead of distinct, parallel queries.

Comment: @Bond - I don't intend to keep on adding to these questions, so hopefully this can be my final one:  New to XML, what are some phrases I should be googling to help fix this? I don't know *anything* about naming conventions, types, etc. for XML, so don't really know even what to search for.  Any ideas for keywords, methods, etc. would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For now, I think my temporary solution (as I brush up on learning other ways to query XML), is to put an `On Error Resume Next` line right before the values are set.  edit: ugh, no I can't do that, because when there is an error, the index for Lat/Long/AltAddress will be one more than County, correct?

Comment: Yep, you're going to have index-alignment issues. I'm going to post an answer to show you how to process your results by `<result>`. One sec...

Comment: @Bond - Yeah, I just tested it. I have an XML with 4 locations, and I removed the `administrative_area_level_2` from the 3rd location in the XML file.  When my script looks for the 3rd location's county, it "jumps" down to the 4th location's `county` and uses that.  Couldn't I just tell it to look for `administrative_area_level_2` ONLY in the parent "formatted_address" that matches `strAddress`? (I see you're replying with a solution, I just am thinking out loud)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I think you'll need to tackle this. First, retrieve all of your `<result>` nodes using `selectNodes()`:

```vb
Set objResultNodes = oXMLFile.selectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result")
```

Then, iterate each of these `<result>` nodes and use `selectSingleNode()` with a relative path to look for children beneath each `<result>` that match your query. Notice how we start with `geometry/...` -- a relative path based on our existing node (`<result>`).

```vb
For Each n In objResultNodes

    Set lat = n.selectSingleNode("geometry/location/lat")
    Set lng = n.selectSingleNode("geometry/location/lng")
    ' ... your other searches    

    If Not lat Is Nothing Then .Range("B" & i).Value = lat.Text
    If Not lng Is Nothing Then .Range("C" & i).Value = lng.Text
    ' ... your other searches       

Next
```

That's how I would go about this. This way, you process each `<result>` as a unit and will be able to tell when `administrative_area_level_2` or some other child node is not available.

Comment: What do I declare `n` as? I'm getting some errors doing this - mainly, do I put the `next` right after I set all those, as you have?

Comment: `n` can be of type `Object` or `Variant`. You'll want to write out your values to your Excel worksheet in the `For` loop. I just added some `MsgBox`es for example, but in your `For` loop, you'd use `Set` and then test to make sure it's not `Nothing` (that it was found, essentially). If so, then `.Range(...) = lat.Text`, for example. I've edited to show what you'd probably be doing here.

Comment: You can get rid of all of your `latitudeNodes` and all other XML-related stuff and just use the loop above. Essentially, you'll have your `oXMLFile.Load()` statement, then go right into setting `objResultNodes` and then this loop.

Comment: thanks (and sorry for the added/removed comments).  One general question then - I should add any other code, such as placing the lat/long in a cell, formatting cells, etc. in that loop.  Each time `n` loops, it's going to be for a NEW address match?  I think I've got it!

Comment: You got it now. I can see the lightbulb from here!

Comment: you have no idea! There were like 10 lighbulbs going off today, all thanks to you!  For real, thanks a million.